# How to make bootstraps 5 entire Card select like radio and checkable like checkbox

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-5

I create react js app and use simple bootstraps 5 cards. I want to make the whole card select as radio like if male or female options and whole card checked like checkable or something we identify selected card.

```
<div class="card" style="width:400px">
   <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Card image" style="width:100%">
 <div class="card-body">
   <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
   <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
 </div>
</div>
```

and normal card see below like

[image]

and after selected see border-color dark and width
[image]

and after selecting, I want the selected card id or values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways to solve this problem. I showing you a very simple example. At first, you set a state and then use this code `const [check, setcheck] = useState('');`

```
<div class="card" style={check === 'male' ? border: '5px solid #000'} : null} onClick={() => setcheck('male')}>
            <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Cardimage" />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card" style={check === 'female' ? {border: '5px solid #000'} : null} onClick={() => setcheck('female')} >
            <img class="card-img-top" src="" alt="Cardimage" />
            <div class="card-body">
                <h4 class="card-title">John Doe</h4>
                <p class="card-text">Some Text</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```